# How to create a prometheus alert which can only be resolved manually

Tags: prometheus, pagerduty

I have a prometheus alert which is integrated with PagerDuty. The alert can be triggered successfully when condition is met. But it will be automatically resolved latter on when condition is not met anymore (just like most other alerts).

But there are some cases in which I do not want the triggered alert resolved automatically, I want them be resolved manually.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: While I believe this question is useful, I think it might be better placed at [devops.se]. Please consider flagging it for moderator attention, and ask to move it there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what can be done (easily) in Prometheus. Prometheus will always resolve alert once corresponding expression stops returning results. Theoretically you can use some trickery with `ALERTS` metric, but in that case you'll need a way to pass a metric to stop said endless alert.

Way easier approach will be to allow Prometheus to resolve alerts as is, and just stop Alertmanager from sending resolutions for some of the alerts.

I suggest adding label to alert rules that you don't want an automatics resolution, like `autoresolve: false`, and then splitting your pagerduty receiver into two: one with `send_resolved: false`, and another - without.

Then apply matchers in your routes like this:

```yaml
route:
  # A default receiver
  receiver: pagerduty-with-resolutions

  # The child route trees.
  routes:
    - matchers:
        - send_resolved="false"
      receiver: pagerduty-without-resolutions
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume above change happen at alert manager part. will try. and let you know if succeed.